# Using Lambda with lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda

I am trying to check if a string object is in a list. Simply written as:

```
if str in list:
```

The problem I am facing is that this list, is not a list of strings, but a list of tables. I understand that nothing is going to happen if I do this comparison directly. What I would like to do is access an attribute of each of these tables called 'Name'.

I could create a new list, and do my comparison against that:

```
newList = []
for i in list:
    newList.append(i.Name)
```

But as I am still a newbie, I am curious about Lambda's and wondered if it would be possible to implement that instead?

something like (... but probably nothing like):

```
if str in list (lambda x: x.Name):
```

Comment: the lambda function is already right there, you're close!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lambdas pretty much doesn't needed here. You can just check it directly:

```
for table in my_list:
    if string in table.Name:
        #do stuff
```

Or using list comprehension, if you want it that way:

```
if string in [table.Name for table in my_list]:
    #do interesting stuff
```

More efficiently, as @Tim suggested, use a generator expression:

```
if string in (table.Name for table in my_list):
```

But if you insist in using lambdas:

```
names = map(lambda table: table.Name, my_list)
if string in names:
    #do amazing stuff!
```

Here's a little demo:

```
>>> class test():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.Name = name


>>> my_list = [test(n) for n in name]
>>> l = list(map(lambda table: table.Name, my_list)) #converted to list, it's printable.
>>> l
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Also, avoid using names of built in functions such as `str`, `list` for variable names. It will override them!

Hope this helps!

Comment: If there are a large number of tables a generator expression should be used rather than a list comprehension.

Comment: Awesome! I like the list comprehension example as well. Very helpful... Cheers

Answer (score 7):

You can write

```
if str in [x.Name for x in list]
```

Or more lazily,

```
if str in (x.Name for x in list)
```

In the latter (with parens) it builds a generator, while in the former (with brackets), it builds first the full list.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you're looking for `any`:

```
if any(x.Name == s for x in lst):
   ...
```

If the list is not large and you need these names somewhere else, you can create a list or a set of names:

```
names = {x.Name for x in lst}
if s in names:
    ....
```

The lambda you wrote is already in python, and called `attrgetter` (in module `operator`):

```
names = map(attrgetter('Name'), lst)
```

Note that comprehensions are usually preferred to that.

Answer (score 2):

you can use filter

```
>>> foo = ["foo","bar","f","b"]
>>> list(filter( lambda x:"f" in x,foo))
['foo', 'f']
```

**update**

i keep this answer because someone may come here for lambdas but for this problem @arbautjc 's answer is better.